# Is it possible to get accurate character/font metrics in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, text, textfield, fontmetrics

I have created a class which will use an embedded font to dynamically generate a bitmap font at run-time.
So far it works well except that I have a minor issue with character spacing.

In the image below the first line is an actual `TextField` and the second has been rendered
using the generated bitmap font.

[image: Character spacing problem example]

If you look at the word 'fox' or the 'ed' of the word 'jumped' you can see that the letter spacing looks a little bit odd.

Are there any alternatives to the `TextLineMetrics` class which will give me more accurate character metrics?

**UPDATE :**

Text rendering quality using the new Flash Text Engine :

[image: Text rendering quality using the new Flash Text Engine]

**UPDATE 2 :**

By chance I have eventually found the solution :

The first problem was the `antiAliasType` property which was set to `AntiAliasType.ADVANCED`.
Although it produces higher quality text it also causes `TextLineMetrics` to return incorrect widths for characters.

The second was that it had to also be rounded up (using `Math.ceil`) to the nearest pixel and not down.

Comment: Maybe it's just a rounding issue. Did you try rounding the pixel value up or down? (or if you are already rounding them, did you try not rounding them?)

Comment: Yes, I did round the position to whole pixels and now I tried not rounding them but it did not make a difference and just caused the characters to become blurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextField is too heavy to that.
flash.text.engine will work better for bitmap generateing

Comment: It looks good so far; using `TextlineMetrics.width` returns inconsistent widths even though I am using a monospaced font but using FTE and `TextLine.textWidth` or `TextLine.getAtomBounds` will correctly return the same width for all characters. The only problem I find is that in my opinion the quality of embedded FTE text is poor, I have included another image to demonstrate the problem - the bottom line looks fuzzy in comparison to the other methods. Is there any way to control the anti aliasing quality using FTE?